# Strange output | rails each do loop over active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

in Rails 5, I am querying via active records relation and pushing each record in array by each-do looping.

```
stats_array = []
pUser = {}

userProject = UserProject.find_by(project_id: params[:projectId], user_id: params[:userId])
if userProject && userProject.project.present?
  projectUsers = userProject.project.users.where(role_id: 1..3).page(params[:page]).per(5) 
  projectUsers && projectUsers.each do |pu|
    pUser[:full_name] = pu.full_name
    pUser[:avatar_url] = pu.avatar.url(:medium)
    pUser[:given] = UserTask.where(to_user: pu.id).joins(:task).count
    pUser[:late] = UserTask.where(to_user: pu.id).joins(:task).where(:tasks => {end_date: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day}).count
    pUser[:wip] = UserTask.where(to_user: pu.id).joins(:task).where(:tasks => {state: @@task_wip_code}).count
    puts "=============================="
    puts pUser # outputs correct details
    puts "=============================="
    stats_array.push(pUser)
  end
end

puts "=============================="
puts stats_array # output wrong details
puts "=============================="
```

in loop when I print user object `pUser`. it prints correctly.
for each different user.

but **the problem is when I print `stats_array`, it prints all the results for single user which ever came last**. the array length is correct but results are not.

**Out Put in Each-Do loop**

> ======== index 0 =======
>
> {:full_name=>"Super User", :avatar_url=>"missing.png",
>   :given=>14, :late=>0, :wip=>4}
>
> ======== index 1 =======
>
> {:full_name=>"Antonio Lingnan",
>   :avatar_url=>"missing.png", :given=>11, :late=>0,
>   :wip=>2}
>
> ======== index 2 =======
>
> {:full_name=>"Uland Nimblehoof",
>   :avatar_url=>"missing.png", :given=>11, :late=>0,
>   :wip=>2}
>
> ======== index 3 =======
>
> {:full_name=>"kU", :avatar_url=>"missing.png",
>   :given=>10, :late=>0, :wip=>2}
>
> ======== index 4 =======
>
> {:full_name=>"Saadi Orlaf",
>   :avatar_url=>"missing.png", :given=>11, :late=>0,
>   :wip=>2}

**Out Put of `stats_array` after Each-Do loop**

> ======== stats_array =======
>
> {:full_name=>"Saadi Orlaf",
>   :avatar_url=>"missing.png", :given=>11, :late=>0,
>   :wip=>2}
>
> {:full_name=>"Saadi Orlaf",
>   :avatar_url=>"missing.png", :given=>11, :late=>0,
>   :wip=>2}
>
> {:full_name=>"Saadi Orlaf",
>   :avatar_url=>"missing.png", :given=>11, :late=>0,
>   :wip=>2}
>
> {:full_name=>"Saadi Orlaf",
>   :avatar_url=>"missing.png", :given=>11, :late=>0,
>   :wip=>2}
>
> {:full_name=>"Saadi Orlaf",
>   :avatar_url=>"missing.png", :given=>11, :late=>0,
>   :wip=>2}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to declare pUser only inside the `.each` loop. My guess is since you're not duplicating the object you're just pushing references to the object on to the array, hence it gets updated to the last one always.

```
stats_array = []

userProject = UserProject.find_by(project_id: params[:projectId], user_id: params[:userId])

if userProject && userProject.project.present?

  projectUsers = userProject.project.users.where(role_id: 1..3).page(params[:page]).per(5) 
  projectUsers && projectUsers.each do |pu|

    pUser = {}
    pUser[:full_name] = pu.full_name
    pUser[:avatar_url] = pu.avatar.url(:medium)
    pUser[:given] = UserTask.where(to_user: pu.id).joins(:task).count
    pUser[:late] = UserTask.where(to_user: pu.id).joins(:task).where(:tasks => {end_date: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day}).count
    pUser[:wip] = UserTask.where(to_user: pu.id).joins(:task).where(:tasks => {state: @@task_wip_code}).count
    puts "=============================="
    puts pUser # outputs correct details
    puts "=============================="
    stats_array.push(pUser)

  end
end
```